# How do I setup a Spark cluster size if my goal is to save/output data into one single file?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a large dataset that I need to process using Spark (Pyspark) into one single CSV file. It's not my choice to output into one file, so I'm trying to figure out how to request a larger cluster to do this processing. I've already encountered memory issues - got `ExecutorLostFailure Reason: Command exited with code 52` so I'm trying to see if I need to increase RAM or anything on the cluster. Assuming dataset exists in delta format across 200 partitions for a total of 1TB, how should the cluster be setup? Do I look to increase RAM? Should I check how much memory spilled to disk in the last run? I don't know what metrics to look for

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure about the feasibility of your problem.

The requirement consists of processing a delta table and then write a single .csv of 1TB. But, writing the output to a single file means that you need a repartition of your data to just one chunk of 1TB. It eventually forces one of the nodes to store all the data in memory and then pass it to the driver to generate the final output. **So you would need two machines (driver and worker) with at least 1TB of RAM**.

**I recommend you to reconsider the option of writing multiple .csv or change the output to a compressed format such as Parquet, ORC, etc.**

2. Some resources explain how to setup an efficient Spark cluster:

- how to choose the memory, cores, executors, etc: [Part 3: Cost Efficient Executor Configuration for Apache Spark](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/part-3-efficient-executor-configuration-for-apache-spark-b4602929262)
- Spark doc about machine provisioning: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hardware-provisioning.html#hardware-provisioning
- A practical example determining Spark resource requirements:
  [Determining Spark resource requirements](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.3/Setup/Determining_Spark_resource_requirements)

3. That's my cluster estimation:

- A delta table across 200 partitions and 5Gb (1 TB total) means that the 200 splits will be distributed to the Spark executors, so **each executor would need at least 5gb of memory to load the chunk, let's say they will use 6gb**.
- **I suggest to get workers of 16 cores and 64 GB RAM** (Databricks instance: Standard_D16a_v4). The idea is to create a general purpose worker as in ([1](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/part-3-efficient-executor-configuration-for-apache-spark-b4602929262)) to do your transformations. **5 executors x 6 gb leads to 30 gb usage. Let's assume that OS and other processes use the other 2 gb per worker.**
  [image]
- **I would start with a few workers and look how the performance increases with new workers.** Here I recommend you to evaluate the trade off between performance and billing.
- **I suggest the same machine for workers and drivers.** The resources are enough.
- Relevant Spark settings inspired in ([2](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.3/Setup/Determining_Spark_resource_requirements)). Do not set number of executors to avoid recomputing the whole setup if you change the worker machine. Executors will be dynamically allocated.

```
spark.executor.memory=6G
spark.executor.cores=3
```

I would not coalesce o repartition to 1 chunk. Just produce the partitioned .csv files as an output and then merge them in a separated process to achieve the final file of 1 TB.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were able to find a single machine that has enough RAM to do this, it would be MUCH faster to write partitioned csv files and then [merge/collate them using some Linux command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/how-to-merge-all-text-files-in-a-directory-into-one).

```py
import os

out_path = os.path.realpath('path/to/csv-files')

# optionally repartition to make it even faster and runnable on normal/cheap machines. 
# You'll have to trade off between time it takes to repartition and time it saves in writing csv.
# df = df.repartition(500) # or partition by appropriate columns

df.write.csv(out_path, header=False)

os.system(f'cat {out_path}/part-*.csv > {out_path}/single.csv')
```

PS: Your partition size is also big, I would go for 2GB per partition (so about 500 partitions instead of 200).